# Can Dispel Magic be used to stop a readied spell from taking effect before the trigger occurs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, readied-action, concentration

NOTE: this does not refer to the case of readying a *dispel magic* spell to stop a spell from being cast as in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55923/can-dispel-magic-be-readied), but rather using *dispel magic* to stop a readied spell from being cast.

---

While writing [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80952/22632), I ran into an interesting corner case regarding the *dispel magic* spell. A readied spell is cast as normal on your turn, but its energy is held (requiring your concentration) until the trigger occurs, after which it is released with your reaction. Would this classify it as an ongoing magical effect (explicitly called out in the description of the [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) spell)?

The rules on spell [duration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Duration) (PHB p. 203) explicitly split spells into "Instantaneous" and "Concentration" sections, mentioning under the latter that (emphasis mine):

> Some spells require you to maintain concentration in order to **keep their magic active**.

However, the official [Sage Advice rules answers column for March 2016](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-march-2016) says, under the question "Can you use *dispel magic* on the creations of a spell like *animate dead* or affect those creations with *antimagic field*?" (bold for emphasis mine):

> Whenever you wonder whether a spell’s effects can be dispelled or suspended, you need to answer one question: is the spell’s duration instantaneous? If the answer is yes, there is nothing to dispel or suspend. Here’s why: the effects of an instantaneous spell are brought into being by magic, but the effects aren’t **sustained by magic** (see *PH*, 203).

How do these rules interact? Can *dispel magic* be used to stop a readied spell from taking effect before the trigger occurs?

Comment: Related, as the two situations complement each other: [Can a readied spell be Counterspelled after it is cast, but before the trigger occurs?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80960/22632)

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference.

Comment: @Christopher if nothing else, *Dispel Magic* having an Action casting time and *Counterspell* having a Reaction casting time make the two cases distinct to me.

Comment: Oh, I see. *Dispel magic* vs. *counterspell*. Two different spells. Gotcha!

Comment: @Christopher the two questions are indeed tightly coupled, as an yes answer to this one **should** imply a no answer to the other one, and a yes answer to the other one **should** imply a no answer to this one. However, they are two separate cases, each with its implications, and discussing both in the same question would be ill fitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, because the spell is no longer instantaneous

The rules on [Readying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) a spell state (PH 193):

> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal [...] and holding onto the spell's magic requires concentration [...] If your concentration is broken, the spell dissipates without taking effect.

Since the spell is now a concentration spell, it should be susceptible to *dispel magic* like any other concentration spell—including being dispelled before the trigger.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. "Instantaneous" refers to the *duration* of the spell's effects. The ready action requires you to concentrate, but doesn't change the spell's *duration* to "concentration".

Comment: While the duration of the effect is instantaneous, there is still a duration between when the spell is cast and when its effect occurs.

Comment: I think the best way of stopping such a spell from being cast is actually neither dispel magic nor counterspell, but instead the spell anti-magic field. drop that on the caster, and he can't even trigger the spell, because the magic gets negated by the field instantaneously.

Comment: Why is this answer the accepted one? :(

Answer (score 11):

### No, *dispel magic* can't be used this way.

*Dispel magic* is not intended to be used until the spell has actually taken effect. Consider the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=15) ruling regarding the [timing of *dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA181). It's pretty clear that the rules intent is that *dispel magic* cannot be used until the spell has actually resolved:

> **Can you ready dispel magic to stop another spell from taking effect?**
>
> The easiest way to stop a spell is to cast *counterspell* on its
> caster while it’s being cast. If successful, *counterspell* interrupts
> the other spell’s casting, and that spell fails to take effect.
> *Counterspell* works against any spell, regardless of a spell’s
> casting time or duration.
>
> With the Ready action, *dispel magic* can be cast in response to
> another spell being cast, yet *dispel magic* can’t substitute for
> *counterspell*. The main reason is that *dispel magic* removes a spell
> that is already on a target, whether that target is a creature, an
> object, or some other phenomenon. *Dispel magic* can’t pre-dispel
> something. If a spell isn’t already present on a target, *dispel
> magic* does nothing to that target. The best that a readied *dispel
> magic* can do is dispel a spell immediately after it’s been cast to
> prevent it from having any effect after the action used to cast it.
> For example, on your turn you could say something like this: “I ready
> *dispel magic*, and if the high priest casts a spell on anyone, I cast
> *dispel magic* on the target if the spell takes hold.” If the high
> priest then cast *hold person* on your companion who fails the save
> against it, you could unleash your readied *dispel magic* and end
> *hold person*.

Comment: According to your own rules answers quote: "The easiest way to stop a spell is to cast counterspell on its caster **while it’s being cast**"; according to the ready action: "When you ready a spell, you **cast it as normal**". Once your turn is over, as the spell has a casting time of 1 action, it has finished casting as normal, and you're simply holding on to it's effect through concentration, so you can't counterspell it. Do you mean to imply there is a period of time during the readied spell's lifetime that it can't be counterspelled **nor** dispelled?

Comment: No, I don't think this is the case. I think the rules clarification makes it clear that the spell, though cast, is not considered "resolved" or "finished" until the effect takes place. For instance, if something causes the caster to lose concentration, the spell fizzles. It doesn't really finish, though the slot is still consumed. It took you an Action to set up the Readied spell (reflected in the casting time). Until it takes effect, it hasn't really been cast, and can be counterspelled. I think this is the only interpretation that makes sense given the rules errata quoted.

Comment: A metaphor would be: It takes you an Action to draw an arrow, pull back the string, and aim. You can Ready to let the arrow fly. You've done all the time-consuming work and have an arrow shot that only takes a reaction to release. *Counterspell* is the equivalent of someone snatching the arrow out of the bow (and breaking it). *Dispel Magic* is the equivalent of pulling it out of the target (and maybe casting a heal spell).

Comment: "The spell, though cast, is not considered resolved or finished until the effect takes place" - I fully agree with you. However, as you say, the spell **has been cast**, and the spell slot consumed. Counterspell specifically says that "You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell" which is not the case here any longer. As an example, just like any summoning spell (which can be dispelled once cast), you finish casting the spell then concentrate on its effect. In the case of readied spells, that effect exists (on the caster, held by him), but is not resolved/finished yet

Comment: By this reasoning, dispel magic cannot work either, according to the quote above, since it cannot be used on the spell, but only on the target affected by the spell. Since there is no spell that does this—using a very strict interpretation of RAW—I think the only sensible alternative is to use RAI as presented above to allow Counterspell to stop a readied spell. The only alternative would be to create a third type of abjuration spell-stopper, and I don't think anyone wants that.

Comment: The quote above does not replace the text in the spell description, which says you can target a "creature, object, or magical effect", ending any spell on the target - a head readied spells fits into those categories, either targeting directly the held spell (a magical effect) or the caster holding the spell (a creature).

Comment: That requires another interpretation: that a spell held ready is "a spell on a target". This interpretation only comes from inference and is not nearly so supported as the clarification from WotC. The intent of each spell is pretty clear (Counterspell stops a spell from happening, and Dispel Magic removes the effect of a previously cast spell), and only a very tenuous line of reasoning supports another interpretation.

Comment: I don't want to belabor the point much further in comment, but if someone can figure out how to formulate the following as a question, I think it deserves further discussion there: under the assumption the Counterspell stops a spell as it is being readied, but then Dispel Magic is required in order to stop a Readied spell — once the trigger occurs and the spell is actually resolving on the target, how is it stopped then?

Comment: There is evidence for this answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99629/can-you-use-dispel-magic-on-the-source-of-a-spell-ie-the-caster) in that you cannot dispel a spell somebody is concetrating on, which is the case when you ready a spell.

Comment: Rather than saying "until the spell has actually resolved", I think it'd be clearer to say "unless a non-instantaneous spell effect has taken place". You're right that *dispel magic* doesn't dispel the held energy of a spell, but rather a non-instantaneous spell effect - whether or not that other spell is readied.

Comment: The more accurate metaphor would be the Counterspell disintegrates an arrow in mid-flight.  A Dispel Magic disintegrates the arrow either notched and waiting to be fired, or the one sticking out of a body already wounded by it.  Since the PHB clearly states, "Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range."  Your target for the spell could be either the caster or the receiver of the spell after the trigger is achieved, showing this metaphor to be the far more accurate one.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, for this specific scenario, you absolutely can!

Dispel Magic is not Counterspell and can't be used as a reaction, as per the rules.  However, in this instance, you are talking about someone having cast the spell and is readying an action earlier in the turn, and on this spellcaster's round (later in the initiative), they cast as their action, Dispel Magic against the readied spell.  **For this specific situation, it absolutely works!**  The description of the [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) spell says (emphasis mine):

> Choose any creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. **For each spell** of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a successful check, the spell ends.

So you can choose the creature who has cast the spell, CHECK.

It is a actual spell we are trying to dispel, CHECK.

The rules for [Readying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) a spell state (emphasis mine):

> When you ready a spell, **you cast it as normal** but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs. To be readied, a spell must have a casting time of 1 action, and **holding onto the spell's magic requires concentration** (explained in chapter 10). If your concentration is broken, the spell dissipates without taking effect.

A spell has been cast, CHECK.

There is magic energy an it is vulnerable to dissipation/dispel by numerous means. CHECK.

The spell has been cast, so it is a done deal, the energy has been activated (slot used) and you are holding the spell energy within the caster.  **There is no way around this very specific fact, by specific over general RAW, *the spell has been cast* before readying it.**  There is an active spell, it is vulnerable to being dispelled/dissipated and losing the already cast spell (and the activated spell slot) by other means, those being loss of concentration or holding on for too long, and reaching your next turn.
The readied spell completely qualifies for the *dispel magic* spell.

This has nothing to do with readying a *dispel magic* spell and using it, this is the other way around, do not confuse the different situations.

The [Sage Advice Compendium ruling](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=15), already quoted about that different situation, is completely correct, in that you cannot dispel a spell not already cast. However, in this instance *the target has specifically cast the spell and the magic energy is active.*

To quote the most pertinent part of the ruling:

> The main reason is that *dispel magic* removes a spell that is already on a target, whether that target is a creature, an object, or some other phenomenon. *Dispel magic* can’t pre-dispel something. If a spell isn’t already present on a target, *dispel magic* does nothing to that target.

The target is the spellcaster, and there is a cast and active spell present on them in the form of the active spell they have readied.  By Sage Advice's own added conditions, the readied spell completely conforms and is vulnerable to the *dispel magic* spell.