# Can a readied spell be Counterspelled after it is cast, but before the trigger occurs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, readied-action, counterspelling

*Based on this question: [Can Dispel magic be used on a readied spell before the trigger occurs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80956/22632)*

Can you Counterspell a readied spell after the turn the original spell is cast as normal, but before the trigger occurs, while you hold its energy using your concentration?

> **Ready** (PHB p. 193)
>
> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs. To be readied, a spell must have a casting time of 1 action, and holding onto the spell’s magic requires concentration.

---

Note that while this and the linked question are related, as an affirmative answer to either of them would strongly imply a negative answer to the other one, they are not duplicates, as there is a possibility (which I am interested in) that both of them could have an affirmative or negative answer at the same time.

Comment: Related: [Can I deny a counterspell by readying my spell behind full cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116751/can-i-deny-a-counterspell-by-readying-my-spell-behind-full-cover)

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201562/when-does-the-duration-of-a-delayed-spell-begin

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### No

> **Casting Time:** 1 reaction, which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell

With a Ready action, the creature casts a spell on its turn and holds it until the trigger; *Counterspell* must be used when they cast  i.e. on their turn. You can *Counterspell* a spell that uses a Ready action, it just has to be on the caster's turn and not after.

As an aside, because Ready uses an action, you cannot use it to cast a bonus action or a reaction spell.

Comment: To confirm, you can still counterspell it when the ready action is announced, correct? Just not after the that turn is over but before the trigger.

Comment: Best thing to do then, to counter the spell, is simply make them lose concentration.

Comment: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/893272974601502720 this might also reinforce your answer