# What does the Wand of Wonder mean when it says "as if you had cast" vs. "you cast"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spellcasting

One of the possible effects of the [*wand of wonder*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-wonder) magic item is (emphasis mine):

> You enlarge the target **as if you had cast** *enlarge/reduce*. If the target can't be affected by the spell, or if you didn't target a creature, you become the target.

There are multiple possible effects for the *wand of wonder* that use a similar wording. There are also many possible effects for the wand that say instead that "you cast [spell]".

Mechanically, what are the differences between the two wordings (if any)? What exact aspects of the spellcasting process/effects are different between the two?

Comment: Related: [Does the shrink effect caused by the Wand of Wonder last the full minute?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128359)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Description vs Mechanics

There is a difference between the phrase

> as if you had cast

and

> you cast [spell name]

The former is using an existing mechanic as a description for an effect, while the latter is stating you are using that mechanic itself with all of the spellcasting requirements detailed in Chapter 11 of the PHB (unless it bypasses those, but that's specific over general.)

If WoTC had meant for them to be equivalent, they'd have used identical language. By utilizing them differently in different places, there is an effective difference.

When **as if you had cast** is used, it is providing the effects without requiring any of the casting rules. Simply by saying **as if**  you are purposefully differentiating from **you did**.

Note also that there is no opportunity for the creature to save against this. It simply states that:

> You enlarge the target...

No save also suggests that this is outside the normal spellcasting mechanics. It's just something that happens and for ease of use it works like an existing mechanic.

### The mechanical differences

Because both of these are spell effects but originate differently, there are different mechanics to apply to them.

#### You Cast

In this case, *you* are casting the spell. You will need to follow all of the general spellcasting rules of Chapter 11 (components, concentration, targeting, etc.) unless the specific description of the item you are using overrides them. Because you are casting, this also becomes subject to a potential *counterspell*.

#### As if

In this case, there is still a spell effect, but it's outside of the general spellcasting rules. You will still follow the description in terms of duration, but this isn't a normal cast spell. Because you haven't actually cast the spell, there are also no concentration mechanics if applicable. The effect is just ongoing for the duration because you haven't actually cast the spell. If you didn't cast it, you don't need to concentrate on it. Think of this like someone casting a buff on you. It's an effect provided by a third party source that you don't have control over.

However, it is still a magical spell effect and would be affected by other abilities and things that would normally work. There is still a reference to the spell and that it works *as if you cast it*, but you didn't cast it and it's just a spell effect created by something external. This also means that the effect is not available for *counterspell*, as there is no actual casting. But it is still a spell effect (because the description is referencing that spell), so you could use *dispel magic* or some other spell/ability that interacts with spell effects or magical effects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89258/discussion-between-rubiksmoose-and-nautarch).

Comment: Sorry I can't agree with this at all. [as if](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20if) means "as it would be if" meaning this is just another terrible word choice to confuse people. P 141 of the DMG says that magic items that allow the casting of concentration spells that users must maintain them unless the item specifically says otherwise.

Comment: There are no secret rules. Picking and choosing which parts of the spellcasting rules to ignore based on "you cast" vs "as if you cast" seems very strange. The writers of D&D aren't perfect and identical clones of each other, so they'll occasionally use slightly-different phrasings that mean the same thing.

Comment: @Slagmoth While I'm starting to question my own answer, what do you think about items like the Animated Shield, which use the description "as if you are wielding it." If that is the same as wielding it, then being proficient in it would seem to be required in order to use this item. [We have a question on that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77539/does-using-an-animated-shield-count-as-wielding-a-shield-for-unarmored-defense), and it seems to think that does bypass the requirement/penalty, which suggests as if is different.

Comment: "as if" would still be replaced with "as it would be if". The fun part is that the rules for magic items in the DMG don't have specific rules governing proficiency. It is reasonably assumed that if you find a suit of armor +1 you would have to be proficient to use it effectively because it is, of course, armor as defined in the PHB rules. The only one that overrides this is Elven Chain to my knowledge. So *technically* you are not wielding it but for all intents and purposes you are treated as though you are.

Comment: TBH, at my table I wouldn't impost the penalty for non-proficiency for animated shield because it is based on physically holding it and not knowing how to handle the weight and bulk efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

*You enlarge / {shrink} yourself as if you had cast Enlarge Reduce on yourself.*

### It's a statement linked to a particular spell<sup>1</sup>

I think that you are over-complicating this semantic / usage difference.

The only two "as if you had" statements have to do with the same spell's effect (*Enlarge Reduce*, 2d level, transmutation) which make the magical effect to either shrink or enlarge (caster's choice) a target.  The wand casts the spell (not the caster) thus "wand casts it as if you had" to create the magical effect.

#### But wait, the wand always chooses! Roll d100 for results

For this particular spell, when the caster chooses themselves *the caster won't get a saving throw* since a saving throw is for an unwilling creature.

> If the target is unwilling, it can make a Constitution saving throw<sup>1</sup>.

(I can see different DM's choosing to rule differently on that due to the overarching "spell save DC 15 versus effects" ... but more below).

- Compare this to the 98-00 roll, where the save versus petrified is spelled out.  So too the 91-95 roll, and the save versus being blinded.

#### Enlarge or shrink, with no save, for the wand's wielder

The wand splits that spell's magical effect into two discrete effects so that it either enlarges or shrinks the caster (or target) *without the caster getting to choose*.  When you cast the spell, the caster chooses, but with the wand casting "as if you had" then the wand / die roll chooses.  Usually, when a caster casts Enlarge Reduce on themselves, they don't role a saving throw against that spell because they want to enlarge or reduce: they are not an unwilling target<sup>1</sup>.

"As if you had" means that the wielder grows or shrinks if the target can't be affected by the spell - that spell effect backfires on the wand's wielder.

The general case for this wand is:

> "If the effect causes you to cast a spell from the wand, the spell’s save DC is 15."

#### This wording also avoids a fizzle.

Since the wand has variable results, the wielder could be trying to cast a spell at something that is not an eligible target creature. (Even though the wand's results are always driven by a die roll ...)  In the case of this roll, 50-53 on the d100 roll (or 66-69 for shrink), in a situation where the target is an ineligible object or creature, the spell would otherwise fizzle if the wand description says "you cast Enlarge Reduce."  (As it says for haste, faerie fire, etc).

This change in language telegraphs an intent: if what you are aiming at can't be enlarged or reduced, then the spell is cast on the wand's wielder.

- Note: this wand and the Wild Magic Sorcerer subclass's Wild Magic feature have some very similar results when triggering the magical effect.  If one looks at this item and attempts to capture the spirit of the item, and the chaotic nature of the outcomes, rather than beating the semantics out of it, I think the interpretation becomes clearer.  Your grow or shrink, *[Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland)*. (And if a white rabbit shows up, so much the better!)

  Each other casting listed will otherwise adhere to casting rules, since "you cast the spell, and save DC is 15" is the overriding guidance.  The rolls 50-53, and 66-69 are uniquely tied to Enlarge/Reduce with no saving throw.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Enlarge Reduce* spell text excerpt

> You cause a creature or an object you can see within range to grow
>   larger or smaller for the Duration. Choose either a creature or an
>   object that is neither worn nor carried. **If the target is unwilling,
>   it can make a Constitution saving throw.** On a success, the spell has
>   no effect.
>
> If the target is a creature, everything it is wearing and carrying
>   changes size with it. Any item dropped by an affected creature returns
>   to normal size at once.

Comment: @NautArch Ok, I'll revise that.  In fact, I just got rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been mentioned, there are also fringe cases that work differently; especially around "contingency" and prepared actions.

If there is a standing effect that takes place "When {character} casts a spell", it will *not* trigger in this case: you produce an effect that is indistinguishable from actually casting the spell, but you did not actually cast anything.

For example: the enemy wizard stating "I will cast 'dispel magic' to counter a spell cast by {character}" will be out of luck.  You did not cast anything, so the enemy wizard doesn't get his counter.

Comment: You can't [ready dispel magic to work like counterspell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55923/can-dispel-magic-be-readied). But the rules around counterspell do apply ( see the last paragraph in my answer)